# Should purchasing the game immediately unlock all levels?

Tags: game-design, level-design, in-app-purchase, progression

I am planning to release my first game as an in-app purchase.

When the user buys the game, they own the entire game. If they can't skip a stage because of its difficulty, they can't unlock the next stages, but they should be able to use the entire game they own.

On the other hand, if all stages are open or if there are infinite coins, the game has no dignity and it loses its sense of effort and competition.

How can I address this problem to not block paying customers from enjoying their purchase, while also not trivializing the effort for those players?

Comment: Based on your description, Is it a [buy-to-play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buy-to-play) game with **extra** [microtransaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microtransaction)(IAP)?

Comment: Thank you very much @Mangata for your guidance

Answer (score 5):

There is a reason why the most common design choice for progression in games is a more or less linear series of unskippable challenges: Earlier stages often teach the player important skills which they are going to need to properly enjoy later stages. This is called a "difficulty curve".

A common method used in "invisible tutorials" is to present the player with a challenge that is impossible to overcome without using a certain strategy, but becomes trivial if that strategy is employed. This can be a challenge as trivial as "press E to open door", but it can also be a complicated but powerful combination of moves they learned before.

Such an invisible tutorial stage is usually followed by a series of stages where the skill that was just taught gets practiced. This reinforces the knowledge and turns it into muscle memory. For example, when you just taught the player how to open doors, then the next stage should include a whole lot of doors to open, so pressing E as soon as there is a door ahead will become an automatic reflex.

This means that when you design later levels, you can assume that the player is familiar with the mechanics they had to use to complete earlier levels. This allows you to use those mechanics in more challenging and less obvious ways or to introduce mechanics that build upon them.

Now imagine the player skipped those stages that teach and reinforce the knowledge of how to open doors. Now they are in a stage that has a pretty complex puzzle and one element they need to proceed is hidden behind a very inconspicuous door. They aren't aware that doors even can be opened, so they won't be able to reach that element. So they will get frustrated by the seemingly impossible challenge ahead of them.

So by forcing the player to complete the content in your game in a specific order, you can ensure that the player always has all the knowledge they need to properly enjoy the game and have a good game experience. If players gets stuck on certain challenges nevertheless, then that's a sign that you as a designer made a mistake: You didn't properly teach them the skills they need to proceed. Allowing the player to skip that stage would make the problem **worse**: They don't learn the more advanced skills *this* stage was supposed to teach them, so the next stage will be an even more frustrating experience for them. The proper solution is usually to insert some obligatory stages in between which provide teaching and practice in the skills the players need to overcome this difficulty spike.

**Conclusion:** Only let the player skip stages if those stages don't teach them anything they are going to need later. For example, especially difficult "bonus challenges" that require a level of mastery of a certain skill that is beyond what is required to finish any other stages.

---

However, there is also another reason why players might want to skip stages besides those stages being too difficult: The stage being **too easy**. The player might have already mastered the skill the stage is supposed to teach and reinforce, so completing it becomes a chore. In that case it might be useful to offer a way to complete such a stage quickly by demonstrating mastery of that skill. For example, a stage that is intended to practice some simple jumping through repetition might be completable instantly by performing a complicated double-walljump-airdash-interrupt technique that actually gets taught a couple stage later.

Adding intentional "skips" like that can also make the game interesting to speedrunners. However, you need to be careful to ensure that the skip only becomes possible if the player *definitely* mastered *everything* the stage is supposed to teach them. If the player skips the stage by accident, they might find themselves in a situation where they lack a required skill and get stuck.

Comment: Thank you very much @Philipp for the time you spent and your excellent and complete guidance, I will definitely use them in making my game

Answer (score 2):

I've seen some games add an "Unlock all levels" option in the settings menu.

So by default, levels are locked, and unlock in some staged order, using game mechanics like the ones Zibelas describes. This means that most players, just playing what's in front of them in the default state, get a satisfying feeling of progression as their effort unlocks more and more of the game, and a gradual escalation in challenge from early to late game (so they can't accidentally jump into a late game level with an exacting test of a skill they haven't practiced in an earlier teaching level, and have a frustrating time).

But for players who get stuck, or who previously unlocked levels on another account/device and don't want to play through every one again, they have a way to skip this gradual unlock if they go looking for it (or check on the game's help page)

You can distinguish two distinct visual states for a level that's been unlocked vs one that's been completed (or completed to a given level of perfection as Zibelas describes), so even a player who hits "unlock all" can still get an enjoyable feeling of progression from turning all their unlocked levels into completed/perfect levels, filling in the gaps on their checklist.

Comment: Thank you very much @DMGregory for your tips. I am new in this website thanks if you edit my question

Answer (score 1):

Congratulation for your soon first game release. There are a number of ways this can be done that depend on what kind of game you are having and how it is played.

- The next level could unlock by X failed attempts in the previous level.
- Automatically after X amount of time (each day one more stage unlocks) or playing time spent in the previous level.
- Watching an ad. If your game is paid, ads might feel wrong to the player since they paid for it.
- By paying an ingame collectable currency (this could be spent on upgrading the character or used to skipping a level)
- By having a certain level of perfection/ stars. If a level can be cleared and you can evaluate how good (barely, good, perfect) and award a currency that is just used for unlocking next levels. The player would get initially 3-X levels unlocked and needs to have Y stars to get the next ones. This has the benefit that not every level needs to be done perfectly

Comment: Thank you very much @Zibelas for your excellent methods, I will use them certainly